# Imported icon vs resource icon

Tags: winforms, icons

What is the difference between importing icon images directly to the control, or include them as resources, in a Windows Form application? What are the advantages of each approach?

Comment: "Best practices" questions are not on topic here.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I guess there is not a concrete problem. Should I close this question? Is there any StackExchange site for programming best practices or similar?

Comment: The advantage of resource files is that that their contents can be easily changed by people who are not programmers and don't have access to the source code. For example, a localization team. I and everyone else recommend using resources unless there's a specific reason not to do so. (Or you're creating a simple test application, in which case the overhead of resources is unnecessary since you don't plan to maintain it long-term anyway.)

Comment: Edited question to make it more Q&A style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put icon directly to control, then icon will be saved directly to .resx file of form.

If you using icon from Resource then control using only reference to resource. if you using same icon directly to control N times, then size of file of form(yourform.resx) will be more then you use only reference to same icon from resource

*Embedded*

File saved directly to yourProject.resx file.

*External*

File added to project folder and .resx file keep only a path to the file

[MSDN Adding and Editing Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: What does "saved directly to control" mean?

Comment: @CodyGray, if you open a .resx file of form, then you will see a bin-data of icon.